# Problem with method recognition in classes, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: methods, subclass, base-class

When I want to call a method from within a upperclass it doesn't seem to recognize the method even though my program does seem to recognize my classes.

For instance

```
    private decimal Fee { get; set; } = 1.5m;

    public new void MethodCredit(decimal amount)
    {
        if (Fee < amount)
        {
            Account.**MethodCredit**(amount - Fee);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fee is greater than the amount you want to transfer");
        }
    }
```

The method doesn't seem to exist anyone who knows what the problem is.

Here's the code inside the main Account class

```
public void MethodCredit(decimal amount)
{
    balance += amount;      
}
```

Comment: To get your problem you should post the complete class. Since upperclass or better "parent" or "super" class is heavily relying on that.

Comment: If you want to have two classes with the same method MethodCredit(decimal) just but one method into the parent class and one into the subclass.

Comment: the parent wont have then access to the subclass' method.

Comment: And if you want to access the parents method you so should use "base.MethodCredit(amount-Feed)"

Comment: maybe thats the problem.

Comment: jup I wanted to use the parent-class method inside the subclass. Using base instead of the name of the parent class worked the charm thank you.